# Resize handlers on Cappuccino

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

how do I add the resize handlers to a CPView in Cappuccino? I saw an example that has rotation handlers, but I want to resize the view freely.

[Rotate example](http://cappuccino.org/learn/demos/FloorPlan/index-deploy.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the exact same concept, but slightly easier... 
I wrote this a while back to do what you want... it should help. 
https://gist.github.com/1623499

Comment: Sorry, but could you give me a complete example please? I don't know what to do with that example. Thanks

Comment: It's a view that the user can resize themselves... You treat it like any other view.